# How can I aligned my content even without hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four columns with diff divs, the fourth column is hover. You have to mouseover the fourth column before the input bar shows up. My problem is, since the fourth column is hidden, the data on the first column goes to the fourth column. Help me with this. Here's my code: 
jsfiddle.net/kerokeroppi/DYvCz/!

[screw up when my fourth column is not hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HkO1.jpg)

[image: When hover my table is fixed.]

[image]

Comment: jsfiddle.net/kerokeroppi/DYvCz/!

Answer (score 3):

use [visibility:hidden](http://www.css4you.de/visibility.html) instead of display:none to hide it.